# Test with Spock if there's null values in a list

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

I am testing a class that has a list items in it. The values are getting inserted via scanner from user input. I want to test the list just before the add method to check if there's null values. I am providing you what I've done so far. I am completely new to Spock and Groovy.

**CLASS TO BE TESTED**

```
package inventory;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Menu {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void printMenu(String[] options) {
        for (String option : options) {
            System.out.println(option);
        }
        System.out.print("Choose your option : ");
    }

    private static final String[] options = {
            "1- Adding an Item ",
            "2- Create and Print the Json file of Items",
            "3- Create and Print the Html file of Items",
            "4- Create and Print the Xml file of Items",
            "5- Create and Print the Csv file of Items",
            "6- Exit"
    };

    public static void addingItemsFromUserInput() {

        int option = 1;
        while (option != 7) {
            printMenu(options);
            try {
                option = scanner.nextInt();
                switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Please enter the Name of the Item: ");
                    String name = scanner.next();
                    System.out.print("Please enter the Serial Number of the Item: ");
                    String serialNumber = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the Item Value");
                    BigDecimal amount = scanner.nextBigDecimal();
                    Item item = new Item(name, serialNumber, amount);
                    addingAnItem(item);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TrackingFile tFileJson = new JsonFile(items);
                    tFileJson.createTheFile();
                    tFileJson.writingTheFile();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    TrackingFile tFileHtml = new HtmlFile(items);
                    tFileHtml.createTheFile();
                    tFileHtml.writingTheFile();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    TrackingFile tFileXml = new XmlFile(items);
                    tFileXml.createTheFile();
                    tFileXml.writingTheFile();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    TrackingFile tFileCsv = new CsvFile(items);
                    tFileCsv.createTheFile();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    scanner.close();
                    System.out.println("Have A Nice Day!");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer value between 1 and " + options.length);
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
    }

    // Options
    public static void addingAnItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() throws RuntimeException {
        if (items.contains(null)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Name cannot be null");
        }
        return items;
    }

}
```

**ACTUAL TEST**

```
def "cannot save if name is null"(){
        given:
        Menu menu = new Menu()
        menu.items.contains(null)

        when:
        menu.getItems()

        then:
        RuntimeException e = thrown()
        e.message == "Name cannot be null"
    }
```

I am receiving the following stack trace. Can please someone help me, to overcome this.

> Expected exception of type 'java.lang.RuntimeException', but no exception was thrown
> Expected exception of type 'java.lang.RuntimeException', but no exception was thrown
> at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.checkExceptionThrown(SpecInternals.java:81)
> at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.thrownImpl(SpecInternals.java:64)
> at inventory.MenuSpec.cannot save if name is null(MenuSpec.groovy:55)

Comment: Given (`menu.items.contains(null)`) is wrong/false! ;)  To make it true, you'd have to `menu.itemd.add(null)`! ..and also consider to validate there (on "adding"!?)

Comment: Test just passed!!! Thank you very much. If you want, write your comment as an answer, to upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    given:
    Menu menu = new Menu()
    menu.items.contains(null)
```

`contains` does not modify the list and simply returns true/false. The return value is never used.

You really want to add the item to the list, not check if it is there (it isn't, you have never added it):

```
    given:
    Menu menu = new Menu()
    menu.items.add(null)
```